# Nested objects and collection in output of Powershell cmdlet not showing up

Tags: c#, powershell-module

I am developing Powershell binary module using C#. I found that the nested objects and collections are not showing up onto console. All other properties are showing correctly. I have not derived the output class from PSObjects. They are plain C#. It contains a bunch of properties,  collections (list and dictionary) and a nested object. The nested object showed the class name only. List showed just the first property.

I tried using Array ([]) instead of list and converted a dictionary as a collection of name, value property class and show it as array.

I want the inner object and object in list to be expanded.

Comment: For help with your code: *show* your code.

Answer (score 0):

**PowerShell calls `ToString()` on nested objects to display them.** You can use derived properties (defined in `Types.ps1xml` files) or custom formatting (defined in  `Format.ps1xml` files) to expose certain properties of the nested objects to show up by default in the console, but otherwise PowerShell is just going to display a flattened version of your object, whether that be the class name (if `ToString()` is not overridden) or whatever you've defined yourself.

For example, I work on a module that uses both `Format.ps1xml` and `Types.ps1xml` files to control how types are displayed. In `Types.ps1xml` we choose the default display properties and also add a custom property to rename a nested object (modified for anonymity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Types>
  <Type>
    <Name>ObjectA</Name>
    <Members>
      <MemberSet>
        <Name>PSStandardMembers</Name>
        <Members>
          <PropertySet>
            <Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name>
            <ReferencedProperties>
              <Name>ID</Name>
              <Name>Name</Name>
              <Name>Description</Name>
              <Name>Metadata</Name>
            </ReferencedProperties>
          </PropertySet>
        </Members>
      </MemberSet>
      <ScriptProperty>
        <Name>ObjectSecrets</Name>
        <GetScriptBlock>$this.Secrets.ToString()</GetScriptBlock>
      </ScriptProperty>
    </Members>
  </Type>

  <Type>
    <Name>ObjectB</Name>
    <Members>
      <MemberSet>
        <Name>PSStandardMembers</Name>
        <Members>
          <PropertySet>
            <Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name>
            <ReferencedProperties>
              <Name>Name</Name>
              <Name>ObjectA</Name>
              <Name>Directory</Name>
            </ReferencedProperties>
          </PropertySet>
        </Members>
      </MemberSet>
    </Members>
  </Type>
</Types>
```

Note that `ObjectB` has a reference to the nested object `ObjectA`. `ObjectA` overrides `ToString()` to return its own `Name` property:

```
> Get-Objects

Name           Directory                ObjectA
----           ---------                -------
some-cool-name X:\some\random\directory objecta-name
```

More about Format.ps1xml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml

More about Types.ps1xml: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml